# Logical issue with while statement in java method

Tags: java, crash, while-loop

Background Information :

I'm developing a battleship game and in the game I have a 10x10 int[][] (the grid).

I've developed a method which trys to hit a cell on that array or grid as long as the same spot hasn't already been tried. (This is for the computer ofcourse playing against me).

```
    public boolean randomShot()
{
    int row;
    int col;
    boolean wasHit = false;
    boolean complete = false;

   while (complete == false)
   {
    // Randomly generate a row and column
       row = randomizer.nextInt(ROW_COUNT);
       col = randomizer.nextInt(COLUMN_COUNT);

    if(compShots.contains("" + row + col) == false)
    {
        complete = true;
        if(checkHit(row, col) == true)
        {
            wasHit = true;

        }
        compShots.add("" + row + col);
    }

   }
    return wasHit;
}
```

The above method works fine and i'm happy with it.

The problem :

I wanted to develop a method that is based off the above method however the computer acts a little smarter in the sense that lets say if he hit row 3 and column 3. Then it would next try to hit row 3 and column 4 etc. however if the next column or row is over the boundary of the board then it would try do it the other way.

The while loop is crashing the game at the moment, any idea why?

This is the method I have to hit the array with a little more brain so to say

```
    public boolean randomShotClever()
{
    int row;
    int col;
    boolean wasHit = false;
    boolean complete = false;



   while (complete == false)
   {

    // Randomly generate a row and column
       row = randomizer.nextInt(ROW_COUNT);
       col = randomizer.nextInt(COLUMN_COUNT);

       if(previousRows.size() == 0 || compShots.contains("" + (previousRows.size() -1) + (previousCols.size() -1) ))       
       {
           finalRow = previousRows.get(previousRows.size());
           if((finalRow + 1) < (ROW_COUNT -1))
           {
               finalRow = finalRow + 1;
           }
           else 
           {
               finalRow = row;
           }

           finalCol = previousCols.get(previousCols.size());
           if((finalCol + 1) < (COLUMN_COUNT -1 ))
           {
               finalCol = finalCol + 1;
           }
           else 
           {
               finalCol = col;
           }

           if(compShots.contains("" + finalRow + finalCol) == false)
           {
            complete = true;
            if(checkHit(finalRow, finalCol) == true)
            {
                previousCols.add(finalCol);
                previousRows.add(finalRow);
                wasHit = true;
            }
            compShots.add("" + finalRow + finalCol);
           }

       }


   }
    return wasHit;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Why do `if (complete == false)` when you can do `if (!complete)`?

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep that in mind. It's just not been my concern making the code tidy at the moment, since i'm not very experienced and just trying to do everything simple etc. I've made a right bodge up of this attempt though :(

Answer (score 0):

Comparison is backwards on

```
if((finalRow + 1) > (ROW_COUNT -1))
       {
           finalRow = finalRow + 1;
```

And again in

```
       if((finalCol + 1) > (COLUMN_COUNT -1))
```

"If I am too big, make me bigger".

There may be others like it.

Comment: Looks like this method is a logical mind field, not only have I written it so badly it's so easy to lose concentration on what is happening, for me at least. If anyone wants to have a go at fixing it, this is what i've come up with so far but it's throwing an OutOfBounds exception on finalRow = previousRows.get(previousRows.size()); Updated method code is now in the question.

Comment: Doesn't `size()` return the number of elements? If there are 10 elements, and you want the "last row", would that be element `9` (so `previousRows.get(previousRows.size()-1)`?  I strongly recommend you think about programming this as a state machine - for each state, what you do is different. You go around a while loop with a switch() statement, execute code for that state, update state, go around again. Possible state values include: START, NOHIT, SHIPHIT, SHIPDIRKNOWN, SHIPSUNK, GAMEOVER. See what you can do with that.